# How to load new content to Fancybox3 after already opened?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

How to load new content after Fancybox3 alreay opened
without close current Fancybox.

I try to make gallery page by using fancybox3 + masonry + infinite scroll

the problem is my opened Fancybox doesn't load new image that new content that load by ajax.

a new content will be loaded when Fancybox reaches to the last element in current gallery.

```
function loadFancy(){
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        selector : '[data-fancybox="gallery"]',
        afterShow: function(instance, current) {
            if (current.index  ===  instance.group.length - 1) {
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can get reference to current instance and use `addContent` method to add new gallery item:

```
$.fancybox.getInstance().addContent({
  'type' : 'image', 
  'src'  : '/path/to/your/image.jpg'
});
```

btw, If you are wondering why this method is not documented, then this method originally was planned to be private method for internal use, but you can use it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to implement a solution for this? I'm having the exact issue.

Here's what I have so far:

```
// Fancybox
$().fancybox({
    selector: '[data-fancybox="images"]',
    loop: false,
    beforeShow: function(instance, current) {
    // When we reach the last item in current Fancybox instance, load more images with Infinite Scroll and append them to Fancybox 
        if (current.index === instance.group.length - 1) {
            alert ('End of the line');
            // 1. Trigger infinite scroll to load next set of images
            $container.infiniteScroll('loadNextPage');
            // 2. Get the newly loaded set of images <--- ????
            // 3. And append to this instance
            // instance.addContent({
                // 'type' : 'image', 
                // 'src'  : '/path/to/your/image.jpg'
            // });
        }
    }
});
```

Edit: Okay, I managed to get this working with the following:

```
// Fancybox
$().fancybox({
    selector: '[data-fancybox="images"]',
    loop: false,
    beforeShow: function(instance, current) {
    // When we reach the last item in current Fancybox instance, load more images with Infinite Scroll and append them to Fancybox 
        if (current.index === instance.group.length - 1) { // 1. Check if at end of group
            // 2. Trigger infinite scroll to load next set of images
            $container.infiniteScroll('loadNextPage');
            // 3. Get the newly loaded set of images
            $container.on( 'load.infiniteScroll', function( event, response ) {
                var $posts = $(response).find('.post');
                // 4. Set up an array to put them in
                var newImages = [];
                $($posts).each( function( index, element ){
                    // 5. Construct the objects
                    var a = {};
                    a['type'] = 'image';
                    a['src'] = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
                    // 6. Add them to the array
                    newImages.push(a);
                });
                // 7. And append to this Fancybox instance
                instance.addContent(newImages);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps anyone who's having the same problem!

The load time of appending the new images to Fancybox is slightly less than desirable, but hopefully this can be optimised with a bit of tweaking.